# Difference between Application.CurrentCulture and Thread.CurrentCulture

Tags: c#, .net, culture, currentculture

Can someone tell me the difference between `Application.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentCulture`.

Thread has `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture`. But Application has only `CurrentCulture`. Why?

I am refering this link mentioned below :

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

[`Application.CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) delegates to `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`(*"Gets or sets the culture information for the current thread"*) so it only sets it for the main thread of the application. In .NET 4.5, you can use the [`CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to change the culture of an AppDomain.

Here's the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Application.cs,e4eb019ded44acc8,references) of `Application.CurrentCulture`:

```
public static CultureInfo CurrentCulture 
{
    get {
        return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    }
    set {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: `DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` will not change anything. It will be set to the threads which are created after that instance of time. By that I mean, existing thread's culture will not be affected.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: i haven't used that property since i'm still using .NET 4, but the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says something different (f.e.: _"If you have not explicitly set the culture of any existing threads executing in an application domain, setting the DefaultThreadCurrentCulture property also changes the culture of these threads"_).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, documentation says something different. Maybe I'm wrong, but that property is really confusing. It turns out that it overwrites the culture for existing threads if you've not set it before.